# How to change the character length for all character variables in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am using the following code to change the length of all character variables in my dataset. I am not sure why this loop is not working.

```
   data test ; 
   set my.data; 
   array chars[*] _character_;
     %do i = 1 %to dim(chars); 
       length chars[i] $ 30  ; 
     %end; 
   run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing data step and macro commands, for one. `%do` is macro only, but the rest of that is data step only.  You also need the `length` statement to be the *first* time the variable is encountered, not the `set` statement, as character lengths are not changeable after first encounter.

You either need to do this in the macro language, or do this with some other data-driven programming technique (as user667489 refers to some of).  Here are two ways.

Macro based, using the `open` group of functions, which opens the dataset, counts how many variables there are, then iterates through those variables and calls the length statement for each (you could identically have one length, iterate through the variables, and one number).  This is appropriate for a generic macro, but is probably more difficult to maintain.

```
%macro make_class_longer(varlength=);
data class;
  %let did=%sysfunc(open(sashelp.class,i));
  %let varcount=%sysfunc(attrn(&did,nvars));
  %do _i = 1 %to &varcount;
    %if %sysfunc(vartype(&did., &_i.))=C %then %do;
      length %sysfunc(varname(&did.,&_i)) $&varlength.;
    %end;
  %end;
  %let qid=%sysfunc(close(&did));

  set sashelp.class;
run;
%mend make_class_longer;

%make_class_longer(varlength=30);
```

Similarly, here is a `dictionary.columns` solution.  That queries the metadata directly and builds a list of character variables in a macro variable which is then used in a normal length statement.  Easier to maintain, probably slower (but mostly meaninglessly so).

```
proc sql;
  select name into :charlist separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname='SASHELP' and memname='CLASS' and type='char'
  ;
quit;

data class;
  length &charlist. $30;
  set sashelp.class;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Length of variables is determined when a data step is compiled, so the first statement that mentions a variable usually determines its length. In your example, this is the `set` statement. Once fixed, a variable's length cannot be changed, unless you rebuild the whole dataset.

To get the result you want here, you would need to move your `length` statement above your `set` statement, and consequently you would also need to explicitly specify all the names of the variables whose lengths you want to set, as they would not otherwise exist yet at that point during compilation. You can do this either by hard-coding them or by generating code from `sashelp.vcolumn` / `dictionary.columns`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of logical and syntactical errors in that code.

The main logical error is that you cannot change the length of a character variable after SAS has already determined what it should be.  In your code it is determined when the SET statement is compiled.

Another logical error is using macro %DO loop inside a data step.  Why?

Your example LENGTH statement is syntactically wrong. You cannot have an array reference in the LENGTH statement. Just the actual variable names.  You could set the length in the ARRAY statement, if it was the first place the variables were defined.  But you can't use the `_character_` variable list then since for the variable list to find the variables the variables would have to already be defined. Which means it would be too late to change.

You will probably need to revert to a little code generation.

Let's make a sample dataset by using PROC IMPORT. We can use the SASHELP.CLASS example data for this.

```
filename csv temp;
proc export data=sashelp.class outfile=csv dbms=csv ;run;
proc import datafile=csv out=sample replace dbms=csv ;run;
```

Resulting variable list:

[image]

This is also a useful case as it will demonstrate one issue with changing the length of character variables. If you have assigned a FORMAT to the variable you could end up with the variable length not matching the format width.

Here is one way to dynamically generate code to change the length of the character variables **without changing their relative position** in the dataset.  Basically this will read the metadata for the table and use it to generate a series of name/type+length pairs for each variable.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select varnum
       , catx(' ',name,case when type='num' then put(length,1.) else '$30' end)
    into :varlist
       , :varlist separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns 
  where libname='WORK' and memname='SAMPLE'
  order by 1
  ;
quit;
```

You can then use the generated list in a `LENGTH` statement to define the variables' type and length.  You can also add in FORMAT and INFORMAT statements to remove the `$xx.` formats and informats that `PROC IMPORT` (mistakenly) adds to character variables.

```
data want ;
  length &varlist ;
  set sample;
  format _character_ ;
  informat _character_;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: This makes sense. I am a stata user, so sas is not intuitive at first. But this explanation is very useful for me. Thanks so much.